# moment-timezone gives inconsistence timezone abbrevation

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm experiencing inconsistent timezone abbreviations when using Moment-Timezone:

Case 1: When I use `moment('2023-09-21T22:37:17.972Z').tz('Asia/Singapore').format('M/D/YY h:mm A (z)')`, I get `'9/22/23 6:37 AM (+08)'`, which displays the offset as `'+08'`.

Case 2: When I use `moment('2023-09-21T22:37:17.972Z').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('M/D/YY h:mm A (z)')`, I get `'9/22/23 4:07 AM (IST)'`, which displays `'IST'` as the abbreviation.

I want to consistently display abbreviations like `'IST'` instead of `'+08'`. How can I achieve this consistency?